# I'm trying to create a HTTP request test with Laravel. But I'm having trouble with cookies

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm  trying to create a simple test that sends a request to my admin's project route.
But I'm having trouble with the cookies. I'm following the Laravel's docs, from version 6.
I've tried different approaches, none of them were successful.

That's the code:

```
public function se_usuario_autenticado_consegue_acessar_admin() : void
    {
        $user = Usuario::find(54158);

        $response = $this
            ->withSession([
                'tipo' => [
                    '****', '****', '****', '****'
                ],
                'poder' => ****,
                'acesso' =>  [
                    '****', '****', '****'
                ],
                'email' => '*****'
            ])            
            ->withCookie(cookie('****', '****'))
            // ->withoutExceptionHandling()
            // ->withoutMiddleware()
            ->actingAs($user)
            ->get('/admin');
        
        $response->dumpHeaders();

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

And the ErroException that I'm getting is

```
ErrorException: Trying to get property 'cookies' of non-object
/home/baldo/Documents/CEISC/CEISC/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/CookieSessionHandler.php:69
/home/baldo/Documents/CEISC/CEISC/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php:97
/home/baldo/Documents/CEISC/CEISC/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php:87
/home/baldo/Documents/CEISC/CEISC/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Store.php:71
/home/baldo/Documents/CEISC/CEISC/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php:165
/home/baldo/Documents/CEISC/CEISC/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithSession.php:45
/home/baldo/Documents/CEISC/CEISC/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithSession.php:28
/home/baldo/Documents/CEISC/CEISC/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithSession.php:15
/home/baldo/Documents/CEISC/CEISC/tests/Feature/HomeTest.php:56
```

Also, as It seems, the withCookies() or withCookie() methods are not working even though they are mentioned in the documentation.

Edit:
This is my TestCase file

```
<?php

abstract class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    /**
     * The base URL to use while testing the application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';

    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        $this->clearCache();

        return $app;
    }

    /**
     * Clears Laravel Cache.
     */
    protected function clearCache()
    {
        // $commands = ['clear-compiled', 'cache:clear', 'view:clear', 'config:clear', 'route:clear', 'config:cache'];
        $commands = ['clear-compiled', 'cache:clear', 'view:clear', 'config:clear', 'route:clear'];
        echo(PHP_EOL);
        foreach ($commands as $command) {
            \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call($command);
            echo('Command ' . $command . ' executed' . PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The proper method is `withCookies` not `withCookie`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#cookies

Comment: I tried both. Also, the documentation says "You may use the withCookie or withCookies methods to set cookie values before making a request. "

Comment: I never noticed that, I always use `withCookies` and pass it an array. But note that you are passing an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie` to it, and not the key/value argument expected. Should be `withCookie('foo', 'bar')` or `withCookies(['foo' => 'bar'])`

Comment: Yeah, I tried it too. The problem is that somewhy the "withCookie" and "withCookies" methods are retrieving error. ```Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Feature\HomeTest::withCookie()```

Comment: Well that should have been in your question. Is your test class extending the correct class? Should be extending `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`

Comment: I found it just now. I reordered the method calls, and then the error appeared. I was extending a TestCase file that I created following some tutorial. I wrote 2 other tests and they worked. And the documentation tell us to use ```PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase```... I will try with that one you told me. Thank you!

Comment: I think typical Laravel install includes the user-defined class `Tests\TestCase` that extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`, and then your tests would extend `Tests\TestCase`.

Comment: Yeah, I was using the Laravel class Tests\TestCase. But it isn't recognizing the ```withCookies()``` method.

Comment: I edited the question and added my TestCase file

Comment: You should update to show the stack trace from your error message, and include your test class.